# access always returns -1, even when the file exists

Tags: c, file-io

I'm having a bit of a problem with a lab I'm working on for school.
What it's supposed to do is check to see if a file exists or not. My code works fine except one line, when I try to check to see if the file exists or not. Even if the file exists, it's returning as if it's not there always. Yet if I hard code the file name into the program it works fine. I'm just trying to figure out what's causing the file name to be interpreted wrong when I pass it into accept (or fopen I've tried both).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
//open lab4.in
FILE *file = fopen("lab4.in", "r");
if (file == 0) {
    printf("Unable to open lab4.in for reading");
    exit(-1);
}

//get the file name to check
char filetocheck[120], output[12];
fgets(filetocheck, 120, file);
int i;

//open lab4.out for writing
unlink("lab4.out");
FILE *write = fopen("lab4.out", "w");


fgets(output, 12, file);

//check the file is there and write the characters to lab4.out 
if (access(filetocheck, F_OK) == -1){
    for (i=5; i<10; i++){
        fputc(output[i], write);
    }
} else {
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        fputc(output[i], write);
    }
}

//close the files at the end
fclose(write);
fclose(file);
```

}

Comment: -1. I need more information. I've read your question, but I have no idea what happens when the program is run. You must give us full details of what happens when the program is run. You have to do the hard work of identifying which lines of code are succesfully processed. For example, you should print the contents of `filetocheck` so that you can be sure it's correct. `printf("<%s>\n", filetocheck);`

Comment: Oddly, a couple of us managed useful answers anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, when an I/O operation like this fails, as well as the -1, you get a result in a global `int errno;`

Where you have your printf, replace that with

```
  perror(argv[0]); /* or something else useful. See below */
```

and add the declaration

```
  int errno;
```

between your `#include`s and the `int main`, and you'll get a useful error message.

(PS: Two things to check: make sure the file's where you expect it, and use `ls -l` to make sure it's readable.)

**Update**

Dammit, that's what I get for not checking the man page.  The argument to `perror` is indeed a string, used to preface the error message.

Comment: On a modern system, the `int errno` declaration does not actually work (because errno is thread-local).  `#include <errno.h>` is canonical.  Otherwise good answer.

Comment: You don't pass `errno` to `perror()` - the function takes a `char *` pointing to a string, not an `int`.  An example of a correct invocation is `perror("access");` - no declaration of `errno` is even required, all you need is the declaration of `perror()` (from `stdio.h`).

Comment: ah crap.  It ain't what you don't know that hurts you, it's what you think you know that ain't so.

Answer (score 4):

In this statement:

```
fgets(filetocheck, 120, file);
```

you may be getting an unwanted carriage return as part of your filetocheck buffer.

Comment: thanks, I actually found that out right after I posted this. Didn't know it was picking up the \n. Wrote a bit to null that out and now it works fine.